# How to get pre selected value in dropdown jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im populating the dropdown with the selected value like this,

```
  <select id="myselect">
       <option value="1">One</option>
       <option value="2">Two</option>
       <option selected="3">Three</option>
     </select>
```

To access the selected option im using:

```
 var myOption = $('#myselect option:selected').val()
```

Here myOption returns "Three" as the value. How do i get the value i.e "3" and not the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3" selected >Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A comment to your answer, It selects the text "Three" because it does not have a value.

Answer (score 0):

you write selected=3 its not correct attribute check below code

```html
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <select id="myselect">
           <option value="1">One</option>
           <option value="2">Two</option>
           <option value="3" selected>Three</option>
         </select>
    <script>
    var myOption = $('#myselect option:selected').val();
    alert(myOption);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set value="3" and add additional property selected(just the tag as it is boolean in nature)

Try the below html code:

```
<select id="myselect">
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3" selected>Three</option>
 </select>
```

$('#myselect option:selected').val() should give you "3"